# Все возможные комбинации элементов списка

Tags: python, комбинаторика

Есть словарь

```
ages = {
    "45-64": 0.025671085927991368,
    "65+": 0.0018149553095834115,
    "35-44": 0.040190728404658656,
    "18-24": 0.37733412203543515,
    "13-17": 0.35014384408604765,
    "25-34": 0.20484526423628374
   }
```

Из которого надо взять ключи (список возрастных групп) "45-64", "65+", "35-44", "18-24", "13-17", "25-34". Как можно из него получить все возможные уникальные комбинации элементы которой разделены строкой age:

```
age18-24age35-44
age13-17age25-34age35-44age65-
age18-24age35-44
age13-17age25-34age45-54age65-
age13-17age18-24age25-34age55-64age65-
ну и т.д
```

Порядок сортировки не важен, главное уникальность. Т.е. age18-24age35-44 и age35-44age18-24 это дубликат, т.к. сумма их значений будет одинаковая.

Comment: Модуль itertools. Там наверняка найдётся что-нибудь подходящее, то ли permutations(), то ли combinations().

Comment: приведите пример входных данных, состоящий из 3-х ключей и укажите в ответе выходной список (вам список нужен?) в __полном__ виде (без "ну и т.д."). В текущей формулировке непонятно что вы хотите получить...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
import itertools

ages = {
    "45-64": 0.025671085927991368,
    "65+": 0.0018149553095834115,
    "35-44": 0.040190728404658656,
    "18-24": 0.37733412203543515,
    "13-17": 0.35014384408604765,
    "25-34": 0.20484526423628374
   }

age_comb = []

# собираем список из комбинаций длиной от 1 до 6 (общее количество элементов) 
# разделенный строкой "age"
for l in range(1, len(ages)+1):
     age_comb = age_comb + list(map("age".join, itertools.combinations(ages, l)))

print age_comb
```

Результат:

> ```
> ['25-34', '45-64', '65+', '13-17', '18-24', '35-44', 
>
> '25-34age45-64', '25-34age65+', '25-34age13-17', '25-34age18-24', '25-34age35-44', 
> '45-64age65+', '45-64age13-17', '45-64age18-24', '45-64age35-44', '65+age13-17', 
> '65+age18-24', '65+age35-44', '13-17age18-24', '13-17age35-44', '18-24age35-44', 
>
> '25-34age45-64age65+', '25-34age45-64age13-17', '25-34age45-64age18-24', 
> '25-34age45-64age35-44', '25-34age65+age13-17', '25-34age65+age18-24', 
> '25-34age65+age35-44', '25-34age13-17age18-24', '25-34age13-17age35-44', 
> '25-34age18-24age35-44', '45-64age65+age13-17', '45-64age65+age18-24', 
> '45-64age65+age35-44', '45-64age13-17age18-24', '45-64age13-17age35-44', 
> '45-64age18-24age35-44', '65+age13-17age18-24', '65+age13-17age35-44', 
> '65+age18-24age35-44', '13-17age18-24age35-44',
>
> '25-34age45-64age65+age13-17', '25-34age45-64age65+age18-24', 
> '25-34age45-64age65+age35-44', '25-34age45-64age13-17age18-24', 
> '25-34age45-64age13-17age35-44', '25-34age45-64age18-24age35-44', 
> '25-34age65+age13-17age18-24', '25-34age65+age13-17age35-44', 
> '25-34age65+age18-24age35-44', '25-34age13-17age18-24age35-44', 
> '45-64age65+age13-17age18-24', '45-64age65+age13-17age35-44', 
> '45-64age65+age18-24age35-44', '45-64age13-17age18-24age35-44', 
> '65+age13-17age18-24age35-44', 
>
> '25-34age45-64age65+age13-17age18-24', '25-34age45-64age65+age13-17age35-44', 
> '25-34age45-64age65+age18-24age35-44', '25-34age45-64age13-17age18-24age35-44', 
> '25-34age65+age13-17age18-24age35-44', '45-64age65+age13-17age18-24age35-44',
>
> '25-34age45-64age65+age13-17age18-24age35-44']
> ```

*(Результат вывода для наглядности разделил на блоки по количеству элементов.)*

Если "age" нужно еще в начале каждого элемента, то нужно еще разок пройтись по списку и добавить.

Comment: `от 1 до 6 ` точнее от `1 до 5`: `list(range(1, 6))` -> `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`

Comment: @gil9red Ай, точно! Надо исправить.

Comment: Круто, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

в данном случае, при использовании словаря, можно воспользоватся его свойством keys который вернёт список всех его ключей. отсортировать, отобрать уникальность, вставить разделить, как в вашем случае age, уже не проблема. вот пример из того варианта входных данных что вы дали:

```
ages = {
    "45-64": 0.025671085927991368,
    "65+": 0.0018149553095834115,
    "35-44": 0.040190728404658656,
    "18-24": 0.37733412203543515,
    "13-17": 0.35014384408604765,
    "25-34": 0.20484526423628374
   }
tt = ages.keys()
print (tt)
mstr = ''
for t in tt:
   mstr += 'age' + t
print (mstr)
```

Comment: и в итоге мы получим просто результат конкатенации ключей словарей

Comment: mstr - да, это результат конкатенации. а вот tt  - это набор ключей